# BIO_do_handshake() always return 0

Tags: openssl, sslhandshakeexception

```
 int rtn =  BIO_do_handshake(sbio);

printf("\n.. returns  %d   .. \n",rtn);


if( rtn <= 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in SSL handshake\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

}
```

I write this code from  [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bio_new_ssl_connect)

but the BIO_do_handshake() always  return 0  why ?

the certificates are fine!!

any ideas ??

Please  help me..

thanks

Comment: What does `ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);` print to stderr? What does OpenSSL say is the error?

Answer (score 2):

We really need to see more code, but here's how I use `BIO_new_ssl_connect` and friends. Did you call `BIO_new_ssl_connect`? Did you call `BIO_set_conn_hostname`? Did you call `BIO_do_connconnect`?

The code below connects to www.random.org and prints the result to the screen. There sre some other checks you must do, but they are outside the scope of hot to use `BIO_new_ssl_connect` and friends.

Also, the bio read loop is not robust, so don't use it in production code (the sample serves another purpose). Finally, you could use `ERR_print_errors_fp` for printing errors. In production, I do other things so `ERR_print_errors_fp` is usually not enough (hence the reason for a simple `fprintf`).

---

```
long ret = 1;
unsigned long ssl_err = 0;

SSL_CTX* ctx = NULL;
BIO *bio = NULL, *out = NULL;
SSL *ssl = NULL;

/* Cipher suites, https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html */
const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = "kEECDH:kEDH:kRSA:AESGCM:AES256:AES128:3DES:SHA256:SHA84:SHA1:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM!MD5";

do {
    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_library_init.html */
    ret = SSL_library_init();
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(ret == 1);
    if(!(ret == 1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL_library_init: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break; /* failed */
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_new.html */
    const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(NULL != method);
    if(!(NULL != method))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSLv23_method failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break; /* failed */
    }

    /* http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ctx_new.html */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(ctx != NULL);
    if(!(ctx != NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL_CTX_new failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break; /* failed */
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ctx_set_verify.html */
    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, bio_pin_pubkey_callback);
    /* Cannot fail ??? */

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ctx_set_verify.html */
    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 5);
    /* Cannot fail ??? */

    /* Remove most egregious. Because SSLv2 and SSLv3 have been removed,  */
    /* a TLSv1.0 handshake is used. The client accepts TLSv1.0 and above. */
    const long flags = SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
    long old_opts = SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
    UNUSED(old_opts);

    /* http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html */
    ret = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "random-org-chain.pem", NULL);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(1 == ret);
    if(!(1 == ret))
    {
        /* Non-fatal, but something else will probably break later */
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        /* break; */
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_ssl.html */
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(bio != NULL);
    if(!(bio != NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO_new_ssl_connect failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break; /* failed */
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_ssl.html */
    /* This copies an internal pointer. No need to free.  */
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(ssl != NULL);
    if(!(ssl != NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO_get_ssl failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break; /* failed */
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html#DEALING_WITH_PROTOCOL_CONTEXTS */
    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html            */
    ret = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(1 == ret);
    if(!(1 == ret))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "SSL_set_cipher_list failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break;
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_connect.html */
    ret = BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, HOST_NAME ":" HOST_PORT);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(1 == ret);
    if(!(1 == ret))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO_set_conn_hostname failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break;
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_file.html */
    out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(NULL != out);
    if(!(NULL != out))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO_new_fp failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break;
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_connect.html */
    ret = BIO_do_connect(bio);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(1 == ret);
    if(!(1 == ret))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO_do_connect failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break;
    }

    /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_ssl.html */
    ret = BIO_do_handshake(bio);
    ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

    ASSERT(1 == ret);
    if(!(1 == ret))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "BIO_do_handshake failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", ssl_err , ssl_err);
        break;
    }

    /* Could examine ssl here to get connection info */
    BIO_write(out, "\n", 1);
    BIO_puts(bio, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
BIO_READ_TOP:
    {
        char buff[1536]; int len = 0;

        /* https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_read.html */
        len = BIO_read(bio, buff, sizeof(buff));

        if(len > 0)
            BIO_write(out, buff, len);

        if(BIO_should_retry(bio)) goto BIO_READ_TOP;
    }

    func_ret = SUCCESS;

} while (0);

if(out)
    BIO_free(out);

if(bio != NULL)
    BIO_free_all(bio);

if(NULL != ctx)
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
```

Comment: From `https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_library_init.html`, I see that `SSL_library_init()` always returns 1 and it is safe to discard the return value. Could reduce a few lines from the code.